# 401 on Yammer image request

Tags: angularjs, request, cors, yammer

We're trying to integrate Yammer on our website, getting and putting posts is done, but we have an issue with getting images.

When the user is logged into Yammer, we can show the images with no problem. 
When the user is not logged in to Yammer, the image request will give a `401` Unauthorized.

We tried getting the image blobs dynamically by adding an Authorization header, but CORS will block us this way.

Could anyone give some pointers on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/123456/preview/IMG-20160413-AA0001.jpg',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yammertoken
    },
    responseType: 'blob'
}
return $http(req)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this already? We're facing the exact same problem! Our users have successfully authorized our app to access their data. So with the authentication token, we get their posts and included image links. But when we request the images, we get 401's as well.

Comment: In the end we created a proxy in our PHP backend which was able to get the images serverside. This circumnavigated the CORS issue.

Comment: There must be a way to get the image preview on the frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we created a proxy in our PHP backend which was able to get the images serverside. This circumnavigated the CORS issue.

Comment: This worked for us as well. Important note: the images also require the authorization token for them to be retrieved, so this needs to be added by the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest not trying to subvert authentication for data. Data such as files live behind authentication in order to ensure that only the users who are allowed to see such data can do so.

Have you explored using https://developer.yammer.com/docs/authentication ?